# How to use the value of a Javascript slider

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, json

I am using a JavaScript slider as a plugin in a form, but this is my first working with JS, how do I get the value of the slider to show elsewhere on my page in order for me to use this value as a variable in my php page in order for me to write this to a MySQL database later.

Following is a snippet of the code, the creator says you call the value by using `function slide(ui, value)`, but I have tried and failed... How do I get this value as a php variable such as `$mySliderValue`:

```
<script>
    var slider = $('#slider').CircularSlider({
        radius: 154,
        innerCircleRatio: '0.59',
        handleDist: 96,
        min: 100,
        max: 3000,
        value: 500,
        clockwise: true,
        labelSuffix: "",
        labelPrefix: "R ",
        shape: "Half Circle Left",
        touch: true,
        animate: true,
        animateDuration : 360,
        selectable: false,
        slide: function(ui, value) {},
        onSlideEnd: function(ui, value) {},
        formLabel: undefined
    });
</script>
```

Comment: To get the value in PHP you would need to send it in a request to the server.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using this slider in a form, then i believe that you have to make your own onSlideEnd function that maybe updates a hidden input field with the new slider value:

```
var slider = $('#slider').CircularSlider({
    ...
    onSlideEnd: function(ui, value) { $('#myHiddenInput').val(value); },
    ...
});
```

and then ofcourse remember to make the input:

```
<input type="hidden" id="myHiddenInput" name="slider_value" />
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe the JavaScript value will be on the client side and you would need to preform an http POST request to get it back to your server-side PHP.  Many times, we do this using an asynchronous AJAX request.